# Website loading slowly or not loading after clearing browsing history in IE11 Browser

Tags: internet-explorer-11

1.Clear IE 11 Browsing history, cookies etc.

2.Close the browser

3.Open the browser

4.Navigate to https://www.parcelforce.com

Expected: The parcelforce.com home page should load properly and quickly in IE11

Actual:
Page does not load properly. Also, on refresh the page takes a lot of time to load. Sometimes it may not load.
This issue is happening with IE11 only. Whenever I hit https://www.parcelforce.com in other browsers say chrome, Firefox, safari, website is loading quickly.

Can anyone suggest me what might be the issue with IE11. Should I need to add any code for IE11 to load website quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I reproduced the problem you described. And I found some other things, when using the `address bar` and `enter` key (two or more times) navigation can make the page complete loading. But using `ctrl+R` or `F5` to refresh cannot achieve the same effect. I checked the console in ie11 and did not find any error messages (except warning messages), so I am not sure if it is a compatibility-related issue or other issues in the code.

On the other hand, the Internet Explorer 11 desktop application will be retired and go out of support on June 15, 2022, I recommand that you could use some morden browsers, such as Chromium Edge.

For more about retirement FAQ of Internet Explorer 11, please refer to [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549).

Comment: Thanks Xudong Peng.
If this is a code issue what might be the issue?
Can you please suggest is this CSS issue or any js issue.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't determine the cause of this issue, because it can load normally only after multiple redirects. And when the issue occurs, there is no error message in the console, although you can see that the DOM element has been loaded in the developer tools. And some strange behaviors, for example, when opening the developer tools, using `Ctrl+R` to refresh the page to complete the page loading, but not working when it is not opened.